# VueJS: Bind values to Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Not sure how to explain this question, and I can't find an answer within the documentation.

Basically within my data I have got an array with 2 values, these represent the index of the day of the week. I want to make a `range` component where I can add some additional functionality, for example in my example this will be a range slider with 2 handles, I just haven't added the styles.

```js
Vue.component('range', {
  props: [ 'step', 'min', 'max', 'value' ],
  created() {
    this.minValue = this.value[0];
    this.maxValue = this.value[1];
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 0
    }
  },
  template: `<div>
    <input type="range" name="points" :min="this.min" :max="this.max" :step="this.step" :value="minValue">
    <input type="range" name="points" :min="this.min" :max="this.max" :step="this.step" :value="maxValue">
  </div>`
});

window.app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    'weekdays': [ 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday' ],
    'locations': [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Test Place',
        'hours': [
          {
            'id': 1,
            'weekdays': [ 0, 4 ]
          },
          {
            'id': 2,
            'weekdays': [ 5, 5 ]
          },
          {
            'id': 3,
            'weekdays': [ 6, 6 ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="location" v-for="(location, index) in locations">
    <h3>{{ location.name }}: {{ location.id }}</h3>
    <div class="hours">
      <div v-for="(hour, index) in location.hours">
        <p>Hour ID: {{ hour.id }}</p>
        <range step="1" min="0" max="6" :value="hour.weekdays"></range>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have created a minimal example above. Now, my question is, is there a way without **emitting** the data back to the parent, that I can use `v-model` to change the array based on my 2 sliders within my main component.

So, theoretical example:

```
<range step="1" min="0" max="6" :value="hour.weekdays" v-modal="hour.weekdays"></range>
```

Comment: Why without emitting?  All you would have to do is add a watcher for `minValue` and `maxValue` and then `emit('input', [this.minValue, this.maxValue])` whenever those watchers are called for `v-model` to work on the range component.

Comment: @StevenB. but I would have to put the watchers in the main app? And the main data will be multi-dimensional and it can change depending on the page.

Comment: No, the watchers would be in the range component.  I'm not sure how your data changing would affect the use of the range component, you'd still have to feed it the same type of data and expect that data to be updated.  [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twsvj8pu/) showing it with watchers and emitting.

Comment: @StevenB. Oh I get you now! Thanks for that, didn't know you could do that! Wanna make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` is just syntatical sugar for

```
<some-component
    v-bind:value=""
    v-on:input="">
</some-component>
```

So you can accomplish using `v-model` on the component by adding watchers internal to the component and emitting an event with a value of the array.

```js
Vue.component('range', {
  props: [ 'step', 'min', 'max', 'value' ],
  created() {
    this.minValue = this.value[0];
    this.maxValue = this.value[1];
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    emitOut() {
     this.$emit('input', [this.minValue, this.maxValue]);
    },
  },
  watch: {
    minValue(newVal) {
     this.emitOut();
    },
    maxValue(newVal) {
     this.emitOut();
    },
  },
  template: `<div>
    <input type="range" name="points" :min="this.min" :max="this.max" :step="this.step" v-model="minValue">
    <input type="range" name="points" :min="this.min" :max="this.max" :step="this.step" v-model="maxValue">
  </div>`
});

window.app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    'weekdays': [ 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday' ],
    'locations': [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Test Place',
        'hours': [
          {
            'id': 1,
            'weekdays': [ 0, 4 ]
          },
          {
            'id': 2,
            'weekdays': [ 5, 5 ]
          },
          {
            'id': 3,
            'weekdays': [ 6, 6 ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="location" v-for="(location, index) in locations">
    <h3>{{ location.name }}: {{ location.id }}</h3>
    <div class="hours">
      <div v-for="(hour, index) in location.hours">
        <p>Hour ID: {{ hour.id }}</p>
        First: {{ hour.weekdays[0] }}
        Second: {{ hour.weekdays[1] }}
        <range step="1" min="0" max="6" v-model="hour.weekdays"></range>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```